# How to know the server response in web api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I am developing Web API in MVC with AngularJS for the first time and and I want to know how to show the response message in client side, to show to the user what is happening.

Here is my code:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
   {
        Product prouct = new Product { Id = id };
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            if (prouct != null)
            {
                db.Products.Attach(prouct);
                db.Products.Remove(prouct);
                if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
                {
                    response =  Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                }
                else
                {
                    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                }
            }
            return response;
  }

$scope.DeleteProduct = function (ID) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this product?")) {
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:52795/api/Test',
            method: 'DELETE',
         params: { Id: ID } 
        }).success(function (data, xhr, status) {
            $scope.GetAllProducts();
            console.log(data);
            alert(status);
        }).error(function (xhr, status) {
            console.log(xhr, status);
            alert( status);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: you could use [toastr](http://www.johnpapa.net/toastr100beta/) notification two show error & success message

Comment: What behavior are you getting, and what's your expected behavior? It looks like you're already logging to the console and showing an alert on the client side. Although it looks like you're showing the headers in the alert and not the status as the callback function should be in the form of `function(data, status, headers, config)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **$http().then()** ?

```
$http({
        url: 'http://localhost:52795/api/Test',
        method: 'DELETE',
     params: { Id: ID } 
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        alert(response.data); // This represents the response
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
     // If some error has occured
});
```

For more about http requests read this

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: True .success and .error are deprecated, but they should still work.